# How to trim few bytes of a byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, arrays, trim

I have a long byte array. I need to eliminate the initial 16 bytes. Is there a shortcut do it?

Comment: The most efficient solution would be to leave the array as is and just index 16 additional bytes into it, if you care about that.

Comment: @Jon: I need to pass the new shorten array to another function for further processing

Comment: @NewBie Well, adapt that function to accept something different from an array, then. In fact, using arrays in public interfaces is highly discouraged (yes, the .NET framework does that too; a mistake).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Why? What is the problem?

Comment: @NewBie Well, for starters you wouldn’t even have this question if your method would accept an `IList<byte>` instead of an array: you could just create a wrapper class that transparently maps the index of an array 16 positions further, like Jon suggested, without any changes within your target function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not the most efficient thing, but will do the trick:

```
// using System.Linq;

long[] array = ...;

long[] newArray = array.Skip(16).ToArray();
```

Comment: I have tried that but VS said `skip` is not member of array. Why?

Comment: @NewBie because you didn't have a using System.Linq in the top of the file. SKip is an extension method and not a member of array. The actual error message should say something like "...not an member of and could not find an extension method taking a sometype as it's first argument"

Comment: Wow, LINQ is so convenient! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) 
For example:

```
var array = //initialization
int bytesToEliminate = 16;
int newLength = array.Length - bytesToEliminate; //you may need to check if this positive
var newArray = new byte[newLength]; 
Array.Copy(array, bytesToEliminate, newArray, 0, newLength);
```

Comment: I checked that and failed to eliminate first 16 byte. PLease help

Comment: Array.Copy will not alter the original array, but it will create a copy. Used correctly that copy will have trimmed of the first 16 bytes.

Comment: @NewBie - I made an update to answer with a short example. Anyway, you should read MSDN article to understand how to use it.